# Having problem with the usage of driver find element by (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'am trying to make a bot that auto logins to a website.
In order to write the username I'm trying to use

```
driver.find_element_by_variable("username").send_keys(username)
```

When I'm looking that spesific variable from website on inspect the varible is two word like **matinput formcontrolname**.
On any other website if that varible is one word like **id** I simply write **id** after `by_` and it works what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) won't allow you to use:

```
find_element_by_variable()
```

but you have to use either of the predefined [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120) as listed in the [*By*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) implementation which are as follows:

- *`CLASS_NAME`*= ***class name***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "element_classname")
  ```
- *`CSS_SELECTOR`*= ***css selector***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_selector")
  ```
- *`ID`*= ***id***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.ID, "element_id")
  ```
- *`LINK_TEXT`*= ***link text***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "element_link_text")
  ```
- *`NAME`*= ***name***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.NAME, "element_name")
  ```
- *`PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`*= ***partial link text***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "element_partial_link_text")
  ```
- *`TAG_NAME`*= ***tag name***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "element_tag_name")
  ```
- *`XPATH`*= ***xpath***

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element_xpath")
  ```