# Writing a string to a spesific field with find_element selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I want to write my e-mail automatically to a field on a website.
The code that I'm trying is

```
driver.find_element_by_variable("variable").send_keys(username)
```

Normally I can do what I want on different websites but for this website I guess HTML codes are written little bit different.
Here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c58-0"><input placeholder="jane.doe@email.com" matinput="" 

<input placeholder="jane.doe@email.com" matinput="" formcontrolname="username" type="text"
autocomplete="off" 
class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c58-0 ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-touched"
id="mat-input-0" data-placeholder="jane.doe@email.com" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
```

How should I write the `find_element` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[driver.find_element_by_variable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545804/having-problem-with-the-usage-of-driver-find-element-by-selenium/70545999#70545999) isn't a valid [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120)

---

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.mat-input-element[id^='mat-input'][placeholder='jane.doe@email.com'][data-placeholder='jane.doe@email.com']"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class, 'mat-input-element') and starts-with(@id, 'mat-input')][@placeholder='jane.doe@email.com' and @data-placeholder='jane.doe@email.com']"))).send_keys("berkay_doruk")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: and why did you write 20 ? What's the point of that?

Comment: For the sake of demonstration I have set it as **20**, incase you are using a framework the wait time for presence, visibility and clickability would be defined in the configuration file. It shouln't wait more or less.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure about the correct locator for that element since you didn't share a link to that page, however you can try the following:

1. Get the web element.
2. Click on it
3. After the click send text to it

There are several possible locators that may work for this element. You can try this:

```py
input = driver.find_element_xpath("//input[@formcontrolname='username']")
input.click()
input.send_keys(username)
```